# Selenium Webdriver Python 2.x - select value from the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have problem with select value from list in Selenium Webdriver and Python 2.x. Look at HTML code of my test site and below is my Selenium Webdriver code with my problem.

HTML from my test site (allegro.pl)

```html
 <div class="input-text-wrapper">
                                <input id="main-search-text" type="text" name="string" x-webkit-speech autocomplete="off" required="required"
                                     class="autofocus" 
                                       value=""
                                       placeholder="czego szukasz?"/>
                            </div>
                    
                            <select class="search-type-select" name="search_scope">
                                    <option value="">wszystkie działy</option>
                                    <option value="electronics">Elektronika</option>
                                    <option value="fashion.beauty">Moda i uroda</option>
                                    <option value="household.health">Dom i zdrowie</option>
                                    <option value="baby">Dziecko</option>
                                    <option value="culture.entertainment">Kultura i rozrywka</option>
                                    <option value="sports.leisure">Sport i wypoczynek</option>
                                    <option value="automotive">Motoryzacja</option>
                                    <option value="collections.art">Kolekcje i sztuka</option>
                                    <option value="company.services">Firma</option>
                                    <option value="user">Użytkownicy</option>
                                    <option value="closed">Zakończone</option>
                                <option class="custom-search-type"></option>
                            </select>
                    
                            <input type="submit" value="Szukaj" class="sprite search-btn"/>
                    
                            <div class="search-type-select"
                    >
                                <ul>
                                        <li class=""><a class="active" href="#">wszystkie działy</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#electronics">Elektronika</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#fashion.beauty">Moda i uroda</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#household.health">Dom i zdrowie</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#baby">Dziecko</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#culture.entertainment">Kultura i rozrywka</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#sports.leisure">Sport i wypoczynek</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#automotive">Motoryzacja</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#collections.art">Kolekcje i sztuka</a></li>
                                        <li class="department"><a  href="#company.services">Firma</a></li>
                                        <li class="separator-top"><a  href="#user">Użytkownicy</a></li>
                                        <li class=""><a  href="#closed">Zakończone</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <strong data-filter-id="" title="wszystkie działy">
                                    <span>wszystkie działy</span>
                                    <i class="sprite"></i>
                                </strong>
                            </div>
```

My Selenium Webdriver code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.allegro.pl")
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_id("main-search-text")
searchbox.send_keys("what you search")

#And here is my problem, i wanna choose something from the list:
searchlist = find_element_by_css_selector("select#search_scope/option[text()='Elektronika']").click()

#I try another think here, but also not working:
#Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#search_scope")).select_by_value(baby).click()
```

I seen in location bar "search_scope", but not value was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you want to use `webelement#webelement_name` is applicable for `id` attribute only, but not `name`: `webelement#webelement_id`.

So this `"select#search_scope"` means search for a `<select id="search_scope">` which in your case, considering provided `HTML` sample, should return `False`

Try to use `Select()` as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[name='search_scope']"))
select.select_by_visible_text('Elektronika')
```

If this approach doesn't work, try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="wszystkie dzialy"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Elektronika').click()
```

Comment: Not working, the same reaction like before. In url i can see "search_scope=" but without value. My code:

Comment: What is this `reaction`? Can you share exception log?

Comment: @PythonLearn, check updated answer and let me know the result

Comment: #Loginbutton submit
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="wszystkie dzialy"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Elektronika').click()
    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_id("main-search-text")
    searchbox.send_keys("telewizor")

Only search "telewizor" without choose any position from list. Not click on list. Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I think i find my fault. Look at my first post in HTML code, i think webelement is bad.